# Qual a diferença entre Mkdir e CreateNewFile?

Tags: java

Estou estudando sobre a classe `File` em Java, e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre usar o `mkdir` e o `CreateNewFile`, o `mkdir` cria o diretório que for passado como parâmetro no formato pasta unicamente?

Comment: `mkdir` cria um diretório; `CreateNewFile` cria um arquivo. Não é essa a diferença?

Comment: A resposta dada atende as suas dúvidas? Não se esqueça de marcá-la como aceita clicando no ✅ Essa atitude ajudará a outras pessoas que vierem aqui com a mesma dúvida

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma lida na documentação seria suficiente para você responder sua dúvida:

```
public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException
```

> Atomically **creates a new, empty file** named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.

Por exemplo:

```
     File f = new File("test.txt");
     System.out.println(f.createNewFile()); //true, criando o arquivo
     File g = new File("dir_inexistente/test2.txt");
     System.out.println(f.createNewFile()); //false, pois o diretorio nao existe


public boolean mkdir()
```

> **Creates the directory** named by this abstract pathname.

Ainda há o método `mkdirs()`, que cria um diretório-pai caso este não exista. Por exemplo:

```
File  f = new File("diretorio_pai_inexistente/diretorioX");
System.out.println(f.mkdir()); //false, o diretório pai não existe, logo, `diretorioX` não é criado.
System.out.println(f.mkdirs()); //true e cria tanto o diretório pai quanto `diretorioX`.
```